# Writing a function for acronym, but what condition I have to write to help me get "aa" from "apple apple"

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble declaring conditions to find my acronym. The condition I wrote are:

- if 'head' is blank then remove the blank space.
- if the next letter of 'head' is blank , remove both the letter and the tail.
- if the 'head' and 'tail' are letters, I want the 'head'.
- if the 'head' is blank give me the next letter because that's one of acronym.

But when comes to a letter like "apple apple", it returns  "apape"  because I have problems
managing with the third condition.

```
acronym :: String -> String
acronym [] = []
acronym [x] = [x]
acronym (x:y:xs)
  | x == ' '  =  y : acronym xs -- remove if 'head' is blank(space)
  | y == ' '  =  acronym xs     -- remove both x and y if y is blank(space)
  | x `elem` ['a'..'z'] || x `elem` ['A'..'Z'] && y `elem` ['a'..'z'] || y `elem` ['A'..'Z']
              = x : acronym  xs
  | x == ' ' && y `elem` ['a'..'z'] || y `elem` ['A'..'Z'] =  y :acronym xs
  | otherwise = x : y : acronym xs
```

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you gave a separate, example-based, high-level description of what the function is supposed to do, rather than literally restating what the function's clauses do.

Comment: the output should be finding the acronym of the input. e.g.: input:"Eating Apple"
output should be: "EA". The function I wrote it's basically removing the blank spaces and  the letters that are next from a 'head' letter

Comment: Your first and fourth points seem to contradict each other. What should really happen if the head is blank? Also in your code the fourth guard (starting with a `|`) is never true, because the first guard already filters out all cases where `x == ' '`. Haskell will try each of these guards from top to bottom, so maybe you just want to swap the first and the fourth guard?

Comment: ya, I didn't notice that, I was trying to declare it one by one, but still I can't find a condition that suit for the function.

Comment: If the 'head' is blank, I want the next letter, because that be should part of the acronym.

Comment: The `words` function in the standard Prelude does most of the work for you.

Comment: `acronym = map head . words`

Answer (score 4):

Some general advice:

1. Avoid equality comparisons, unless you know exactly why you want them. Equality is usually better written directly as pattern matches.
2. Avoid doing a lot of stuff in a function. Prefer composing simple helper functions, especially when they're already defined in a library.
   In your case, the problem has an obvious factoring into

   1. Split the string in [words](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:words)
   2. Obtain the first letter for each word

Even short of simply invoking the `words` function to do most of the work for you, it helps a lot to write your own function that splits off *a single word* from a string. You may do that e.g. based on whitespace and pattern matching, like

```
splitOffWord :: String -> (String, String)
splitOffWord "" = ("", "")
splitOffWord (' ':cs) = ("", cs)
splitOffWord (c:cs) = case splitOffWord cs of
   (word, rest) -> (c:word, rest)
```

...or based on letter-ness and with a standard function

```
import Data.Char (isAlpha)

splitOffWord = span isAlpha . dropWhile (not . isAlpha)
```

...or something in between.

Then, in your `acronym` function, you can split off the first entire word, use it for obtaining the first character of the acronym, and recurse over the rest of the input.

```
acronym (' ':str) = acronym str
acronym str = case splitOffWord str of
   (word, rest) -> _ : _
```

...filling in the `_` left as an exercise.